# Java Web Start Not Launching Problem

Tags: java

I've just install New OS windows 7 64bit, After installed java.

I couldn't launch any Java Web Start application from my browser (by downloading and launching a *.jnlp file). When I try to launch an app, the loading cursor spinning for 10-20 seconds then nothing happen. I am getting frustrated with this issue!

Does any one know how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to download the JNLP file localy and starts it using a command : javaws file.jnlp
you will have more informations about the potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

JNLP is a little annoying initially if you don't get it right. I had the same experience, follow [this](http://pedroassuncao.com/2010/10/java-web-start-jnlp-simple-example/) tutorial, it works like a charm.

Also, please post some error/warning message. Your question is very broad.

Comment: i've just don't know what else to explain, when i try to go here https://j3d-webstart.dev.java.net/test/ , launch an app nothing happen..where can i view the error.